# "I'm just like anyone else" or "I am not like other people"?

Tags: phrases, differences

I am translating a Russian phrase, original meaning of which was:

> I am the same as all other people.

A suggested translation is:

> I'm just like anyone else.

I think it should be:

> I am not like the other people.

What are the differences in conveyed meaning between these phrases? Please, help me to clarify...

Comment: And what stops you from using *I am the same as all other people*? Since it is what you want to say...

Comment: Hi, chipvl. Unfortunately, translation requests are considered off-topic for our site. If you hop into the ELU chat room, however, we have lots of people (including some Russian speakers) who would be able to help you.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more on topic (as I see it).  If you object to these edits, you may roll them back by selecting the timestamp link next to "edited" and choosing rollback as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the following two sentences are roughly synonymous, so it would appear to be a fine translation.

> I'm just like anyone else.
>
> I am the same as all other people.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that the two phrases are equivalent.

> I'm just like anyone else.

This means I'm no better or worse than anybody. Usually it is used to reference a specific trait: "I'm just like anybody else. I like a glass of beer and a hamburger now and then."

> I am the same as all other people.

This is broader, and suggests that the speaker matches the entire population of the earth in every measure.

The key difference here is *all* vs. *any*. The former is broad in scope, the latter more narrow and specific.

Comment: Perhaps Everyone else would be a better choice of wording.

Comment: I don't disagree there's a slight variation (hence the *roughly*), however considering the *I am the same as all other people* was also a translation from Russian and perhaps suffered from a lack of precision I didn't want to get too deeply into it, and rather simply wanted to affirm that it meant a similar thing and certainly did not mean the opposite as the OP believed.